# Import all task from another folder with prefect

Tags: python, import, orchestration, prefect

I'm using prefect to orchestrate my function (task) in python.

```
── app
  └── folder   
       └── file1.py (task1)
       └── file2.py (task2)
       └── ....
  └── flow.py
```

I would like to import all the task at once from the folder in flow.py without importing them individually like:

```
from folder import file1 , file2, ....
```

Or by using a `__init__.py` file